# ios 9 vs. ios 9.1 beta

Tags: ios, upgrade, iphone

I am running iOS 9.1 beta and it seems pretty good and more stable than past iOS 9 iterations.

Will my iPhone 5S prompt me to upgrade to the public release of iOS 9 today?

Comment: Does this question, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205903, help?

Comment: thx. helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be prompted to update today since the 9.0 release will be lower than the 9.1 beta you are running. You could downgrade, but that's really dependent upon what your specific needs are going forward.

- [Downgrading from iOS 9.1 Beta to iOS 9 Stable and Keeping Picture Data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205903/)

Comment: I understand the beta concept. I should've been clearer...wondering if I will lose any functionality or options by going with 9.0 over 9.1.

Comment: @Sizzle Wherever on apple.com you downloaded the iOS 9 Beta should have documentation on it, then all you have to do is compare that to the documentation on the public release of iOS 9.

Comment: All - I've chopped the question into two parts. Let's move the "why would I get off the beta train" until that gets asked alone...